# What is the function of the special directory(named debian) to the project design?

Tags: design, project

I am reading a [github project](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/tree/master):

you see there is a directory(`debian`) in there, what the function of it?

[image]

I have browsed the directory, there seems have some configuration files:

`shadowsocks/debian/config.json`

```
{
    "server":"my_server_ip",
    "server_port":8388,
    "local_address": "127.0.0.1",
    "local_port":1080,
    "password":"mypassword",
    "timeout":300,
    "method":"aes-256-cfb",
    "fast_open": false,
    "workers": 1,
    "prefer_ipv6": false
}
```

what's the directory here for? and what is the function to the project design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the debian package files, as one can see by checking the history on one of these files.

https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/commits/master/debian/rules

These are used to produce a .deb file which is the package used in/with the package manager `apt` in debian & ubuntu.

https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian

Comment: thanks your response, but why there is no other directory such as produce a yum package, or other type package ?

Comment: @244boy: Probably because the developers haven't gotten around to it. Or, they don't care about RedHat. Or, they don't use RedHat. Or, they don't know how. Or, they use `alien` to create an RPM from a Debian package.